# What is the syntax for post-incrementing a variable in C?

Tags: c

What is the syntax to increment a C int by 1 after it has been evaluated within an expression?

I want to achieve the following with less code:

```
int a;
int ar[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,8};
int ac = 0;
a ^= a;
ac += ar[a];
a = a + 1;
ac += ar[a];
printf("%x\n", ac);
```

I want to replace `ac += ar[a]; a = a + 1;` with a single statement. How can `a` be incremented in the same statement as `ac += ...`, after it has been evaluated as the array index?

Comment: Like this: `ac += ar[a++];` The main problem, though, is that `a` has not been initialised.

Comment: If this is a question about postfix increment in C, why tag f#, d and e?

Comment: Re the edit, `int a; a ^= a;` is undefined behaviour. It is not guaranteed.

Comment: @lulle it was a typo

Comment: No @user234461, it is *not* guaranteed to be zero.  Local variables declared without initializers have an indeterminate value until a value is assigned to them.

Comment: It reads from an uninitialised variable. That behaviour is what is undefined.

Comment: @WeatherVane Works for me on VSC+++

Comment: "It works for me" does not mean it is guaranteed to work.

Comment: "Works for me" or "Works on machine XY" is the first step into the world of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user234461 Well, that's exactly what undefined behavior means. It can work for you the first time and the next time it can offer you a beer.

Comment: It might *not* work in a different program or with a different compiler (maybe the next version of your current one)  or on a different machine.  Or the 666th time you run the program, or whatever.  If you want reliable behavior then you must know and depend on the semantics specified by the language.  Experimentation is not a particularly good way to figure out what those are.

Comment: @JohnBollinger This is false. There are entire verification methodologies based on the random generation of test cases. Besides, relying on tool-specific quirks is a good way of propagating your or your company's favoured tools and preventing the code from being ported to less favourable platforms.

Comment: @user234461: The existence of entire verification methodologies based on random generation of test cases does not disprove that experimentation is not a particularly good way to figure out the semantics specified by the language.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If everyone understood the semantics of their language then there would be no bugs.

Comment: @user234461: Also not true, as humans make errors even with things they understand, but it is true that humans would make fewer errors and therefore understanding the semantics of the language is a good thing. Nonetheless, both are unrelated to the fact that the existence of verification methods based on random cases does not disprove experimentation is not a particularly good way to learn the semantics.

Comment: Re “What is the syntax for post-incrementing a variable in C?”: Out of curiosity, how does one learn the term “post-incrementing” without learning it is performed using the `++` operator after a variable?

Comment: @EricPostpischil From the ARM VLDR instruction. But one can derive it using simple facts and logic. Fact: post-increment, as I call it, is supported by a lot of hardware, particularly after memory access as shown in the question. Fact: languages and modes of thought are shaped by reality. Fact: In particular, C was heavily influence by HW-specific assembly. So naturally there will be a post-increment operator. Post=after. Increment=add 1. ;D ;D ;D

Answer (score 4):

The postfix `++` operator will evaluate to the current value of its operand and increment the operand as a side effect.

```
ac += ar[a++];
```

As a caution, be careful not to use `a` in the same expression where you use `a++` as that triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You have an unrelated problem with your code however.  You're using `a` without initializing it.  Reading an uninitialized variable that never had its address taken also triggers undefined behavior.

By doing `a ^= a;` you seem to want to set `a` to zero, so just set it: `a=0;`